# Entity Framework - Foreign Key annotation being ignored getting the wrong object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Obligatory "First time question, sorry if I've messed anything up". I just hope someone can help.

Entity framework 6, .net 4.5.

I have a Product. A product might be made from a particular quantity of other products, so I've created a ProductUsed class with two productIDs, one called ParentProductID and one called PreProductID with an annotation on a virtual Product for the foreign key that points to the "PreProductID". Every time I access it, it's loading the product for the ParentProductID.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

//trimmed for brevity 

    [ForeignKey("ParentProductID")]
    public virtual List<ProductUsed> ProductsUsed { get; set; }

}

public class ProductUsed
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductUsedID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pre Product")]
    [Required]
    public int PreProductID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pre Product")]
    [ForeignKey("PreProductID")]
    public virtual Product PreProduct { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    [Required]
    public int ParentProductID { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }


}
```

Saving is done by creating the object, adding it the the parent products ProductsUsed collection and then saving changes. The database has all the fields in the right places.

Everything I've read says that this should be straight forward, it just seems to be ignoring the annotation. Or (as is entirely more likely) I don't understand how that annotation should be working.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have your foreign key in the wrong model. It should look like this:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ProductUsed> ProductsUsed { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ProductUsed> PreProducts { get; set; }

}

public class ProductUsed
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductUsedID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pre Product")]
    [Required]
    public int PreProductID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pre Product")]
    public virtual Product PreProduct { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    [Required]
    public int ParentProductID { get; set; }

    public virtual Product ParentProduct { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }


}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductUsed>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.ParentProduct)
            .WithMany(p => p.ProductsUsed)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentProductID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductUsed>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.PreProduct)
            .WithMany(p => p.PreProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.PreProductID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

The ProductsUsed in Product is then resolved by the foreign key in ProductUsed model.

EDIT: Changed to fluent api model builder.

Comment: Removing the ForeignKey on ProductsUsed results in an exception being thrown of Invalid column name 'Product_ProductID'

With the ForeignKey there it does get the correct ProductUsed objects when I access it, it's just that the Product that was there was pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: Try renaming ParentProduct to Product and ParentProductId to ProductId.

Comment: If renaming doesn't work you can use the fluent api from entity framework. See example [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: I had them renamed as you've suggested before, but the key thing is the PreProduct class has two product references. I actually changed the name as I'd assumed that Entity Framework was picking up the wrong one by referring to defaults - only that didn't help either. 

I have tried the fluent api but I'm not quite sure how to tell it about both sides of the relationship.

Comment: See latest edit. Worked for me with this fluent configuration. The willCascadeOnDelete(false) is there because of circular references in your model.